# Why doesn't this excel formula work?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, formula

```
{=SUM(IF(AND(X3:X130="WEST",AF3:AF130="Yes"),1,0))}
```

It is supposed to check to see how many times a given row has "WEST" in column X and "Yes" in column AF, and I know in the worksheet this happens at least 10 times but the formula always returns zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the construction is incorrect. You can't use [logical operators](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/04/logical-operations-in-array-formulas/) in this way. For further explanation I think you might need an answer from Microsoft.

However there may be an alternative that suits:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((X3:X130="WEST")*(AF3:AF130="Yes"))
```

Note for this `Enter` is sufficient.